# perl - algorithm to replace multiple if statements using mod

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that parses a large files. It works but it is slow and I see a pattern that i'd like to take advantage of, but i don't know how to write it.

there is a section where i count a number of **objectIds**, and have to return a value **Spaces**. The mininum number of ***objectIds** is 3 and increases in odd increments, my output starts at 3 and increases in multiples of three.

So i have a chain of 30 statements like this

```
if($objectIds == 3)
{
    $spaces = 3;
}
if($objectIds == 5)
{
    $spaces = 6;
}
if($objectIds == 7)
{
    $spaces = 9;
}
```

I see that the difference is incrementing by a modulo of 1, i.e. *(3 % 3 = 0)*, *(6 % 5 = 1)*, *(9 % 7 = 2)*, but i can't for the life of me figure out how to optimize this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula should calculate and replace your ifs,

```
# $spaces = $objectIds + ($objectIds-3)/2;
# $spaces = (2*$objectIds + $objectIds-3)/2;
# $spaces = 3*($objectIds -1)/2;

$spaces = ($objectIds -1) * 3/2;
```

Comment: I have about 1 day experience with per so I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for all the help you two. It works like a champ, and allowed me to replace 120 lines of code with 1!!!

Answer (score 0):

The first optimisation I see is to use `elsif` :

```
if($objectIds == 3)
{
    $spaces = 3;
}
elsif($objectIds == 5)
{
    $spaces = 6;
}
elsif($objectIds == 7)
{
    $spaces = 9;
}
```

Comment: I'll update my script and kick it off. It parses files that are between 1 - 8 Gb, so any improvements help! thanks.